# How to put a hyperlink on some words only in a TextField on JasperStudio?

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports

I am currently creating a report with JasperStudio 6.9 and I need to put a hyperlink within a TextField. The report itself will then be sent as a stream through a server. Is there any way to do so in JasperStudio or any workaround?

Currently, I only managed to put the link over the whole TextField from the hyperlink properties in the item's tab but cannot put it only on the words I want. As far as I am aware of, it is not possible to do so, but I wanted to be certain.

I don't really have any code to show since it's all made through the software's UI.

Let's say the TextField has the sentence "Please contact us at this address", I would like the words "This address" to bear the hyperlink, not the entire sentence.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should write something like this in the "Text Field Expression":
`"Contact us <a href=\"mailto:" +  $F{EMAIL_TO} +"\">at this address.</a>"`

or (if the email does not come from the data retrieved ):
`"Contact us <a href=\"mailto:info@yourdomain.com\">at this address.</a>"`

and change the "Markup" property to "html".
[image: markup property]